# How to stop or recover inappropriate downvotes?

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encouraging people to explain down-votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)

Recently I posted an answer to a question. Somebody downvoted it (without leaving a comment). But the solution is working. I have even provided a link to a working demo. How can we stop such kind of downvoting? If someone has done it, how can we recover it? I think by providing a working demo's link I have proven my solution's correctness.

An example of such a downvote is at [How to get the ID of a div when using bind() in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589087/how-to-get-the-id-of-a-div-when-using-bind-in-jquery/10589136#10589136)

Comment: You can't stop downvoting any more than you can stop upvoting.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but maybe the person who did noted that your `SomeFunction` is not the same as the OPs, so while this solution works, it doesn't exactly fit for what the OP needs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sometimes people downvote unjustly and without giving a reason.

Happens all the time.

What do to?

Accept it and move on. Life's too short.

Comment: How do you know it's "unjustly"?

Comment: @TheEstablishment - They downvoted **my** answer, that's how.

Comment: There are several privileges in this site. There can be another one. after having Which people can judge downvotes and remove inappropriate downvotes.

Comment: This is the only possible correct answer. Appropriateness is in the eye of the beholder - we do have mechanisms for invalidating *obviously* inappropriate votes, but the sanctity of the voting system is lost if they kick in too easily.

Comment: @Imdad: If you think that something has been downvoted unfairly, you can use your vote to counter it. But giving someone the power to both redact your vote *and* provide their own is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Being correct is not the only criteria for voting.  Someone might dislike your solution because (I am making this up off the top of my head) it's not clear from `SomeFunction()`'s signature that it relies on `id`.  They may have other reasons related to best practices to simply think that your answer was too similar to the others (and therefore just noise).  And did you test it in every single browser, including all versions? :P

In short, don't presume to know the mind of the voter.  A single downvote on what you think is a good answer may be frustrating, but in many cases it is not inappropriate or abusive.  Unless there is something explicit, like a comment or serial downvoting, it's best to accept it and move on as Oded says.